# Linearization of a max function

Tags: linear-programming

I have to cope with a constraint of the form (1) in the following problem:

$$\begin{align}\max\quad& x+y\\
\text{s.t.}\quad&
x + y \leq \max \{x,y\} &(1)\\  
&0 \leq x \leq U_x&(2)\\ 
&0 \leq y \leq U_y&(3)\\
\end{align}$$

In the following link you can find an approach but I don't understand it.

https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/

I don't understand: what is $S^+$, $S^-$ and how would a penalization look like? 
(I refer to the text: "The max function can be linearized as follows: ..." in the reference).

I would be grateful if somebody could help.

---

[The linked figure shows the problem in LP Format and the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLyjI.jpg)

Comment: $S^+$ and $S^-$ represent the positive and negative parts of $A-B$ respectively. So if $A-B\geq 0$, then $S^+=A-B$ and $S^-=0$, but if $A-B<0$, then $S^+=0$ and $S^-=B-A$. Thereby, $|A-B|=S^+ + S^-$ and $A-B=S^+-S^-$. Or at least, that's the idea. It will only work, as the website says, if you penalize $S^\pm$ in the objective function.

See also https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Optimization_with_absolute_values

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I implemented the problem in cplex lp-format. The problem is solved only if I fix S+ or S- to zero (the correct one). How could the penalization term, in a maximization objective function, look like so that either S+ xor S- becomes zero at the optimum? If I add i.e. the term  - (S+  *  S-) to the maximization objective I end up with a nonlinear problem, which of course is not desirable.

Comment: I think you can just add $-(S^+ +S^-)$ to the objective, you don't need it to be a product. The reason is that since $A-B=S^+-S^-$,  and $S^+,S^-\geq 0$, you can get one of the two to be zero if you minimize the sum of both magnitudes/maximize the negative sum.

Comment: Unfortunately, add −(S+ + S−) to the objective doesn't solve the problem. In my first posting I added a figure (click on the link "¨The linked figure ...") showing an example in LP format. The solution should be 100 (=A) but the optimizer sets S+ = S- = 20 instead of S- =0  and returns 80 as the optimum. Is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reformulation in the link isn't guaranteed to work. In this case, it doesn't, because the feasible region is not convex. You cannot express a non-convex feasible region with linear constraints.

To see that it is not convex, note that if $x\geq y$, then $x+y\leq x$, so $y=0$. Otherwise, $y>x$, so $x+y\leq y$ and then $x=0$. Therefore, either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

We have feasible solutions of $(x,y)=(U_x,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,U_y)$. If the feasible region were convex, a convex combination of those would be feasible, like $(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(U_x,U_y)$. However, it's not feasible unless $U_x=0$ or $U_y=0$.

So for general $U_x,U_y$, you can't use this reformulation. Instead, you'll probably want to introduce a binary variable, and solve a mixed integer programme. Or, in this case, by inspection.

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains why Cplex doens't deliver the result I would expect (like to have).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope it is not too late; the penalty could be representative like this:

> max x + y
> x <=s1 + s2
> y <=s1 + s2
> s1 >= x - y
> s2 >= y - x
> s1 - bigM*b <= 0
>
> s2 - bigM*(1-b) <= 0
> 0 <= x <= Ux
> 0 <= y <= Uy

where b is binary variable

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).